# How can I connect to web service with Bearer token?

Tags: android, web-services, jwt, retrofit2, bearer-token

I'm trying to pull data by connecting to a web service using Retrofit. The web service I will use in my application is encrypted. So I can access it with Bearer token. I also need to renew the Bearer token. I did get Bearer tokens. How can I connect to web service with this Bearer token I got?

Postman : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGrI3.jpg)

ServiceAPI :

```
interface ServiceAPI {


    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("GetToken")
    fun getGetToken(@Field("grant_type")grant_type:String, @Field("username") username:String, @Field("password") password:String):Call<Token>


    @GET("api/Users")
    fun getUsers(@Header("Authorization") authorization: String): Call<UsersModel>

  
}
```

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        getServiceExample()

    }


fun getServiceExample(){
        val BASE_URL = "https://www.exampleserviceid.com/"
        val api = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build()

       

        val service = api.create(ServiceAPI::class.java).getGetToken("password","myusername","mypassword")



        service.enqueue(object : Callback<Token>{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Token>, response: Response<Token>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful){

                     val gettoken: Token? = response.body()
                    val token = gettoken?.accessToken  //  This is how I get the Bearer token
                    

                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Token>, t: Throwable) {
                
                TODO("Not yet implemented")

            }

        })

    }
```

Token :

```
class Token : Serializable {
    @SerializedName("access_token")
    @Expose
    var accessToken: String? = null

    @SerializedName("token_type")
    @Expose
    var tokenType: String? = null

    @SerializedName("expires_in")
    @Expose
    var expiresIn: Int? = null

  
    constructor() {}

    /**
     *
     * @param tokenType
     * @param accessToken
     * @param expiresIn
     */
    constructor(accessToken: String?, tokenType: String?, expiresIn: Int?) : super() {
        this.accessToken = accessToken
        this.tokenType = tokenType
        this.expiresIn = expiresIn
    }

}
```

UsersModel:

```
class UsersModel : Serializable {
    @SerializedName("username")
    @Expose
    var username: String? = null

    @SerializedName("userage")
    @Expose
    var userage: String? = null

 
    constructor() {}

    constructor(username: String?, userage: String?) : super() {
        this.username= username
        this.userage= userage

    }

}
```

How can I connect to web service with this Bearer token I got?

Update :

```
fun getServiceExample(){
        val BASE_URL = "https://www.exampleserviceid.com/"
        val api = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build()

       

        val service = api.create(ServiceAPI::class.java).getGetToken("password","myusername","mypassword")



        service.enqueue(object : Callback<Token>{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Token>, response: Response<Token>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful){

                     val gettoken: Token? = response.body()
                    val token = gettoken?.accessToken  //  This is how I get the Bearer token


val httpClient: OkHttpClient.Builder =OkHttpClient.Builder()
                        .callTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

                    httpClient.addInterceptor(object: Interceptor {
                        override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): okhttp3.Response {
                            val original = chain.request();

                            val request = original.newBuilder()
                                .header("Authorization","Bearer " + token)
                                .method(original.method(), original.body())
                                .build();

                            val Log = Logger.getLogger(MainFragment::class.java.name)
                            Log.warning("Bearer " + token)

                            return chain.proceed(request);
                        }
                    })

                    val client = httpClient.build();
                    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .client(client)
                        .build();

                    val service2 = retrofit.create(ServiceAPI::class.java).getUsers()

service2.enqueue(object : Callback<UsersModel>{
                        override fun onResponse(call: Call<UsersModel>, response: Response<UsersModel>) {
                            if (response.isSuccessful){

                                val usersmodeltoken: UsersModel? = response.body()
                                val usernametoken = usersmodeltoken?.username

                                Toast.makeText(context, usernametoken, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()


                            }
                        }

                        override fun onFailure(call: Call<UsersModel>, t: Throwable) {

                            /*
                            TODO("Not yet implemented")
                             */

                        }

                    })

                    

                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Token>, t: Throwable) {
                
                TODO("Not yet implemented")

            }

        })

    }
```

update postman : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VR43.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution :

```
 @GET("api/Users")
    fun getUsers(@Header("Authorization") authorization: String): Call<List<UsersModel>>
```

```
val service2 = retrofit.create(ServiceAPI::class.java).getUsers("Bearer "+tokennn)


service2.enqueue(object : Callback<List<UsersModel>> {
                            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<UsersModel>?>?, response: Response<List<UsersModel>?>?) {
                                if (response != null) {
                                    if (response.isSuccessful){
                                        val data= response.body()
                                        if (data!= null) {
                                            val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerview)
                                            recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
                                            recyclerView.adapter = ExampleAdapter(data)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<UsersModel>?>?, t: Throwable?) {
                                // TODO("Not yet implemented")
                 
                            }

                        })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
val httpClient:OkHttpClient.Builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
.callTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

httpClient.addInterceptor(object:Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
         val original = chain.request();

        val request = original.newBuilder()
            header("Authorization","Bearer " + tokenVariable)
            .method(original.method(), original.body())
            .build();

        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
}

val client = httpClient.build();

val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()  
    .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .client(client)
    .build();
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you convert the code to kotlin?

Comment: I added the codes. In this line error :                                                                               val service2=retrofit.create(ServiceAPI ::class.java).getUsers()                                                 (No value passed for parameter 'authorization' )

Comment: change from  ```fun getUsers(@Header("Authorization") authorization: String): Call<UsersModel>
``` to ```fun getUsers(): Call<UsersModel>
```

as you are already passing value by okhttp

Comment: I'm getting 401

Comment: add log to check you are not passing blank token for ```tokenVariable``` in ```Interceptor```

Comment: I checked it is not null. I added the latest version of my code to the topic. In the update section.

Comment: code seems good and have you checked api is working or not by calling api in postman ?

Comment: When I write the token I get in the code, I get 401 when I write to postman.. What would be the reason ? also I added a photo with new information about postman